# Is there a possibility to use a composite key for idProperty in dojo/Memory

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

Is there a possibility to use a composite key for `idProperty` in dojo/Memory.
For example: `var test = new Memory({ data: response, idProperty: ['id_user','id_profile',id_center]});`

And if yes, how can I access the id after, will it be `item.id` or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a concatenated id, eg for instance :

. Add a record with something like :

```
myMemoryStore.put({
    id: [someUserName, someProfile, someCenter].join('#'),
    userName: someUserName,
    profile: someProfile,
    center: someCenter,
    ......
});
```

. And then retrieve a record with :

```
user = myMemoryStore.get(["John Smith", "profile X", "center Y"].join('#'));
```

Provided that none of these fields can contain the character '#', it's more secure.